# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 - vscode

Tags: c

I am trying to run a code on VSCode on Mac OS BigSur, 11.5.2.

I am getting this Error on this function

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_insertionSort", referenced from:
      _insertionSort_int in main-ddd159.o
      _insertionSort_char in main-ddd159.o
      _insertionSort_float in main-ddd159.o
     (maybe you meant: _insertionSort_float, _insertionSort_char , _insertionSort_int )
  "_loadfile", referenced from:
      _main in main-ddd159.o
  "_mergeSort", referenced from:
      _mergeSort_int in main-ddd159.o
      _mergeSort_char in main-ddd159.o
      _mergeSort_float in main-ddd159.o
     (maybe you meant: _mergeSort_char, _mergeSort_float , _mergeSort_int )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Pleas help me

Comment: You cant run code on vscode which is only a text editor.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. That would include *minimal* code necessary to reproduce the error and your exact *compilation command*. Before doing that though, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).